# CSS change made with javascript doesn't stick

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

This may not be specific enough to answer but I'm hoping there is some insight. I've been having a problem with javascript that I don't understand. Essentially, which I use `onClick()` to change the style of some element, the change happens briefly (a fraction of a second) and reverts back to the previous state. What could cause such a thing? The web page I'm working on has become pretty big so I don't want to post it and expect you to sort through lots of markup. I'm hoping somebody will recognize this as a common mistake or at least have an idea of where to look for the source of the problem.

Comment: If you could isolate the function that executes with your onClick event handler and post it, that would help.

Comment: `The web page I'm working on has become pretty big so I don't want to post it and expect you to sort through lots of markup` -- Too much information is better than no information at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the page is reloaded after the style is changed, check the `href` in your link, are you preventing the default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not reloading the page as a result of the click.

If you're clicking something like

```
<button onclick="foo()">click me</button>
```

or

```
<a href="..." onclick="foo()">link</a>
```

then the page may be reloaded as a result of the link, either because the `<button>` is using the default [`type`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp) of `submit` or because the link has an `href`.

To fix this, put `; return false` after your `onclick` handler.